# Submitting into database, but through AJAX returns blank

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to insert values from my form into my database.

When I have the form action to the script directly, it inserts:

```
require_once("../../includes/database.class.php");
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];

$title = $_POST['blog-title'];
$content = $_POST['blog-content'];
$image = $_POST['article-image'];
$active = $_POST['active-inactive'];
$comments = $_POST['enable-comments'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO blog_article (blog_title, blog_body, blog_author, blog_image, active, comments) VALUES ('$title', '$content', '$uid', '$image', '$active', '$comments')";

// print_r($sql);
$result = $database->query($sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "Article created.";
}else {
    echo "Query failed" . print_r($sql);
}
```

However, when I set up ajax to handle it without reloading the page, the query submits perfectly. However, the values are blank other that the uid:

```
var submit_button = $('#submit_article');

var data = $("#addarticleform").serialize();

submit_button.click(function() {

    var update_div = $('#update_div');

    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'addarticle.php',
        success: function(html) {
            update_div.html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

I apologize if this is an obvious mistake, I've only just started playing with AJAX.

Comment: Please add html code as well.

Comment: Ive just figured it out. Thanks tho :)

Comment: I'm sure this is still early days for whatever you're working on, but don't forget to sanitize your inputs (on the server side!) before you build that SQL statement.

Comment: I wont. Want to get everything working properly before i rerun through the code and make security edits and adjustments :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. As it turns out, i had

```
var data = $("#addarticleform").serialize();
```

in the wrong place. Should be after

```
submit_button.click(function() {
```

not before it.

Comment: you might just delete this question as a simple typographical error then